# Delete certain rows in Excel over multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I've following code to run within Excel to delete certain rows from the worksheets (multiple worksheets involved) if a column contain certain texts.
Code works if the column happens to be "A" but doesn't work when it is column "C". Not sure if I got syntax wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

```vb
Sub DeleteCertRowsAcrossSheets()
    Dim I&, LastRow&, SheetNum%
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    For SheetNum = 1 To Sheets.Count
        With Sheets(SheetNum)
            LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For I = LastRow To 1 Step -1
                If Left(.Range("C" & I), 9) = "createdby" Or Left(.Range("C" & I), 17) = "createdonbehalfby" Or Left(.Range("C" & I), 9) = "createdon" Or Left(.Range("C" & I), 10) = "modifiedby" Or Left(.Range("C" & I), 18) = "modifiedonbehalfby" Or Left(.Range("C" & I), 10) = "modifiedon" Or Left(.Range("C" & I), 25) = "timezoneruleversionnumber" Or Left(.Range("C" & I), 25) = "utcconversiontimezonecode" Or Left(.Range("C" & I), 13) = "versionnumber" Then .Cells(I, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Next I
        End With
    Next SheetNum
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're only looking at Col A.  There's nothing here for Col C or any other columns.

Comment: On a side note, don't use integers in VBA, make SheetNum% SheetNum& for a long.

Can you post some sample data and explain what would happen in that instance? Is it that the current code works for column A but you want it to work across multi columns? If so I would probably set a range with the find function and delete based on the range maybe? Need more info before we can say 100% though.

Comment: TimWilliams correct, this code is for Column "A" and I updated to Column "C" but did not work. @Dan Donoghue current code works for Column "A" but when I replace the column name to "C" it doesnt work. I tried to put column "C" values to column "A" and it works.

Comment: @zaino22 rather than showing us the dcode that _does_ work, show us the code that _doesn't_, together with some sample data and expected results, and what "did not work" actually means (what didn't it do, what it did do instead, did you get errors)

Comment: @chrisneilsen sorry, I now have added current code in the question that doesn't work.

Comment: @zaino22 where is the rest of the info requested?  I'm going to guess that there is less data in column `A` than in `C`, and therfore your `LastRow` calculation returns the wrong result.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Data is provided in the code where I search for certain text in the column C. After your comment, I tried just moving three worksheet column from C to B and ran the code and weird enough, It did not work. Then I moved column B to column A and it worked. I dont understand what's specific to Column A that works and doesnt with others. Would it be possible to post your solution to achieve this task? Column C is where these text exist in ALL the worksheets.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you very much for your help. In addition, if I were to delete any rows in all the worksheets in a Excel where there is blank in column "C"  (starting from C2 since C1 is header), can I modify code as following: Const CriteriaList As String="" where "" is considered blank?

Comment: That's not gonna work. I've added another version of my initial code which will delete the rows where the cell is blank.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you, code worked for blanks and although majority of blanks were removed however some blanks were not removed. I wanted to check the reason whether there was space character or something else that may have prevented deleting row but there wasn't space so I manually deleted them. I wonder what  prevented these delete.

Comment: Hopefully, the not deleted rows were at the bottom.  The reason behind it is that the last row (cell) was determined in column `C` but there may be data in e.g. column `A` below that. A fix e.g. for column `A`, would be using `"A2"` instead of `"C2"` and adding another constant `Const sCol As String = "C"`. Then you could create the reference to the range with `Set srg = sfCell.EntireRow.Columns(sCol).Resize(slCell.Row - sfCell.Row + 1)`.

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008 I will update "Set srg = sfCell.Resize(slCell.Row - sfCell.Row + 1)" with "Set srg = sfCell.EntireRow.Columns(sCol).Resize(slCell.Row - sfCell.Row + 1)" and try.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Rows Where a Cell's Value Starts With...

- The following will delete each row where the value of the cell in a given column starts with a string contained in `Criteria(List)`. This will happen from the first cell (`sFirst`) to the last non-empty cell in the column and in all worksheets of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteAccrossWorkSheets()

    Const sFirst As String = "C2"
    Const CriteriaList As String _
        = "createdby,createdonbehalfby,createdon," _
        & "modifiedby,modifiedonbehalfby,modifiedon," _
        & "timezoneruleversionnumber,utcconversiontimezonecode,versionnumber"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    Dim crCount As Long: crCount = UBound(Criteria)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sfCell As Range, slCell As Range, sCell As Range
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim sString As String
    Dim n As Long, tCount As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        
        Set sfCell = ws.Range(sFirst)
        Set slCell = sfCell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        
        If Not slCell Is Nothing Then
            
            Set srg = sfCell.Resize(slCell.Row - sfCell.Row + 1)
            ' Or e.g.:
            'Set srg = ws.Range(sFirst, slCell)
            Set slCell = Nothing
            
            For Each sCell In srg.Cells
                
                sString = CStr(sCell.Value)
                
                For n = 0 To crCount
                    ' Not just contains (' > 0'), but starts with (' = 1')... 
                    If InStr(1, sString, Criteria(n), vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                        If drg Is Nothing Then
                            Set drg = sCell
                        Else
                            Set drg = Union(drg, sCell)
                        End If
                        tCount = tCount + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next n
            
            Next sCell
            
            If Not drg Is Nothing Then
                drg.EntireRow.Delete
                Set drg = Nothing
            End If
        
        End If
    
    Next ws
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Select Case tCount
    Case 0
        MsgBox "No rows deleted.", vbExclamation, "Delete Across Worksheets"
    Case 1
        MsgBox "One row deleted.", vbInformation, "Delete Across Worksheets"
    Case Else
        MsgBox tCount & " rows deleted.", vbInformation, _
            "Delete Across Worksheets"
    End Select
            
End Sub
```

### EDIT

- The following will delete each row where the cell in a given column is blank. This will happen from the first cell (`sFirst`) to the last non-empty cell in the column and in all worksheets of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteBlanks()

    Const sFirst As String = "C2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sfCell As Range, slCell As Range, sCell As Range
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim sString As String
    Dim tCount As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        
        Set sfCell = ws.Range(sFirst)
        Set slCell = sfCell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        
        If Not slCell Is Nothing Then
            
            Set srg = sfCell.Resize(slCell.Row - sfCell.Row + 1)
            ' Or e.g.:
            'Set srg = ws.Range(sFirst, slCell)
            Set slCell = Nothing
            
            For Each sCell In srg.Cells
                
                sString = CStr(sCell.Value)
                
                If Len(sString) = 0 Then
                
                    If drg Is Nothing Then
                        Set drg = sCell
                    Else
                        Set drg = Union(drg, sCell)
                    End If
                    tCount = tCount + 1
                
                End If
            
            Next sCell
            
            If Not drg Is Nothing Then
                drg.EntireRow.Delete
                Set drg = Nothing
            End If
        
        End If
    
    Next ws
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Select Case tCount
    Case 0
        MsgBox "No rows deleted.", vbExclamation, "Delete Blanks"
    Case 1
        MsgBox "One row deleted.", vbInformation, "Delete Blanks"
    Case Else
        MsgBox tCount & " rows deleted.", vbInformation, "Delete Blanks"
    End Select
            
End Sub
```